# Hue light nomenclature of versioning change (how to interpret versioning numbers from SW Version)

Tags: versioning, philips-hue

I am trying to understand the way the bridge is displaying the swversion field. With my Lux lamps it used to show "66012040", but after I upgraded the bridge it now shows "5.17.1.12040".

I also bought and added an older Hue light that shows version "5.23.1.13187" (model LCT001). In the Philips release notes it states that there is a software update from 2014 Lamp software version: 66013452 and as I understand it should be applicable to my hue light, but I can't get the bridge to update the light from the API, or by using the official application.

Could someone explain how to translate between the older and newer way of showing the versions? And how can I force the bridge to update the older light?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The format of the swversion for lights changed in API 1.12.
There is no  conversion function that I know of. The Phillips API documentation is frequently not updated in a timely manner, if at all, and just plain incorrect. In this case, neither the old nor the new format is explained anywhere I can find.

My LCT001 bulbs are either "5.23.1.13452" or "5.23.1.13187"

LCT007 bulbs changed from "66014919" to "5.38.1.14919"

LST002 Lightstrip Plus changed from "66015744" to "5.50.1.15744"

Since the version numbers are relatively inscrutable, I wouldn't worry about it. While the numbers on my hub updated automatically, you might have to delete and re-add the light to force an update if you really care.